# strong tag next to quotes creates space

Tags: html

I feel like this is HTML 101, and I'm missing something super obvious, but I couldn't figure out the search terms to find the answer to this.  I have `strong` tags formatted a little differently in my code, and they always get their content pushed to a newline.  If I have a `strong` tag that is inside some quotes, it automatically adds spaces around the strong text.  If I include the quotes inside, I do not get this issue.  If I remove the formatting, I do not get this issue.

I don't understand why the formatting would matter here, and why putting the quotes inside of the strong tag would fix the issue.

```html
<span>
  Quotes outside strong will "<strong>
  have a space
  </strong>"
</span>
<br>
<span>
  Quotes inside strong will <strong>
  "not have a space"
  </strong>
</span>
<br>
<span>
  Quotes outside (but not formatting) will "<strong>not have a space</strong>"
</span>
<br>
<span>
  No quotes with strong will <strong>
  not have a space
  </strong>
</span>
```

Comment: [This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace) was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

that's due to the additional spaces in the HTML code which are created by your linebreaks inside the `strong` tag in the code. If you omit those, there will be no spaces between the quotes and the text inside the tag:

```html
<span>
  Quotes outside strong will "<strong>NOT have a space</strong>"
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Turns out it was HTML 101... duh.

Comment: Turns out this is a *dupe 101*. Why not close so OP can read more about it in the extensive answers on the dupe?